selenium loop over days in calendar (python)
i'm kinda new to python and web scraping. With the help of chatgpt I achieved a lot but i'm currently stuck with a problem for my hobby project. What i'm trying to do is retrieve all available time slots for a restaurant on the days that are still open in the current month, next month and 2 months from now. Everything is working fine for the first month (based on calendar_id) but when I get to the next month it retrieves the corresponding time slots for the first day, but it crashes at the second day. This is the code I currently have:
def fetch_days(driver):
    day_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table[@class='calendar-days']//td[not(contains(@class, 'closed')) and not(contains(@class, 'past')) and not(contains(@class, 'other-month')) and not(contains(@class, 'booked')) and not(contains(@class, 'booked has-event')) and not(contains(@class, 'closed has-event')) and not(contains(@class, 'selected other-month')) and not(contains(@class, 'closed other-month has-event'))]")
    day_numbers = [int(day_element.text.strip()) for day_element in day_elements]
    return day_numbers    

def calendar_data(name, driver):
    driver = initialize_driver(driver)

    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(
            ******
        )
        if conn:
            print("Connected to PostgreSQL database")

            create_table_if_not_exists(conn)
    
        try:
            switch_to_iframe(driver)
            select_ticket(driver)

            date_filter_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="widget"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]'))
            )
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", date_filter_element)
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", date_filter_element)

            click_previous_month(driver) #need to start at the current month

            for _ in range(1, 4): 

                time.sleep(2)

                # find calendar ID
                calendar_id = get_calendar_id(driver)

                month_year_element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'month-select')
                month_year_text = month_year_element.get_attribute('innerText')
                month_year = month_year_text.strip()

                day_numbers = fetch_days(driver)
                print(day_numbers)

                for day in day_numbers:
                    tr_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
                    
                    # Flag to indicate if the desired day has been processed
                    day_processed = False
                    
                    for tr in tr_list:
                        day_xpath = f"//div[@id='{calendar_id}']//tr[{tr}]/td[contains(., '{day}')]"
                        print(day_xpath)
                        retries = 0
                        day_element = None

                        while retries < max_retries:
                            try:
                                day_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, day_xpath)
                                # print(day_element)
                                break  # Found the element, exit the loop
                            except (NoSuchElementException, ElementClickInterceptedException):
                                retries += 1
                                time.sleep(retry_delay)
                                continue

                        if day_element is not None:
                            # Wait for the day element to be clickable
                            day_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, day_xpath))
                            ) 
                            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", day_element)
                            time.sleep(1)

                            day_element.click()
                            # click_element_with_retry(day_element) 

                            time.sleep(1)

                            # Wait for the time options dropdown to be present
                            time_options_dropdown = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                                EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'options.dropdown.time-dropdown'))
                            )
                            
                            # Retrieve and print the time information for each available time option
                            time_options = time_options_dropdown.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'time-option')
                            for time_option in time_options:
                                try:
                                    time_element = time_option.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'time-time')
                                    time_text = time_element.get_attribute('innerText')

                                    availability_element = time_option.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'availability')
                                    availability_text = availability_element.get_attribute('innerText').strip()

                                    insert_data(conn, restaurant_name, month_year, day, time_text, availability_text)

                                    print('Dag:', day, 'tijd:', time_text, 'beschikbaarheid:', availability_text) 
                                except Exception as e:
                                    print("Exception occurred while retrieving time information:", e)
                            
                            time.sleep(1)
                            
                            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", date_filter_element)
                            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", date_filter_element)

                            day_processed = True 
                            break
                    
                    if day_processed:
                        continue

                # Click next month after processing all desired days for the current month
                click_next_month(driver)
        
                # Update calendar_id after clicking next month
                calendar_id += 1

        finally:
            # Close the browser window
            driver.quit()
            print('done')
    
    except OperationalError as e:
        print("Error while connecting to PostgreSQL:", e)

This is the html element (made it smaller than it actually is):
<div class="calendar" id="2029">
            <div class="cal-month">
                <div class="prev-month">
                    <a class="cal-arrow" href="#" ng-class="{'disabled': ctrl.prevDisabled}" ng-click="ctrl.prevMonth()">
                        <svg class="cal-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true" role="img"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#cal-arrow-left"></use></svg>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="month-select">
                    <div class="month-top-line" ng-style="{background:month.color}" style="display: none;"></div>
                    May 2024
                </div>
                <div class="next-month">
                    <a class="cal-arrow" href="#" ng-class="{'disabled': ctrl.nextDisabled}" ng-click="ctrl.nextMonth()">
                        <svg class="cal-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true" role="img"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#cal-arrow-right"></use></svg>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="weekdays">
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <!----><td ng-repeat="day in ctrl.weekDays">
                                Mon
                            </td><!----><td ng-repeat="day in ctrl.weekDays">
                                Tue
                            </td><!----><td ng-repeat="day in ctrl.weekDays">
                                Wed
                            </td><!----><td ng-repeat="day in ctrl.weekDays">
                                Thu
                            </td><!----><td ng-repeat="day in ctrl.weekDays">
                                Fri
                            </td><!----><td ng-repeat="day in ctrl.weekDays">
                                Sat
                            </td><!----><td ng-repeat="day in ctrl.weekDays">
                                Sun
                            </td><!---->
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <table class="calendar-days" stop-event="">
                <tbody>
                    <!----><tr ng-repeat="week in ctrl.month.weeks">

                        <!----><td ng-repeat="day in week.days" ng-click="ctrl.openDay(day, $event)" title="Click for more info" ng-class="{
                                'closed': day.status === 1,
                                'past': day.status === 2,
                                'booked' : day.status === 3 || day.status === 5,
                                'waiting-list': day.status === 6 &amp;&amp; !day.otherMonth,
                                'selected': ctrl.isSelected(day),
                                'today': ctrl.isToday(day),
                                'other-month': day.otherMonth,
                                'has-event': day.message
                            }" class="closed other-month has-event">
                            <div class="span-wrap">
                                <span ng-style="day.fontColor &amp;&amp; {'color': day.fontColor }">
                                    29
                                </span>
                                <!---->
                            </div>
                        </td><!----><td ng-repeat="day in week.days" ng-click="ctrl.openDay(day, $event)" title="" ng-class="{
                                'closed': day.status === 1,
                                'past': day.status === 2,
                                'booked' : day.status === 3 || day.status === 5,
                                'waiting-list': day.status === 6 &amp;&amp; !day.otherMonth,
                                'selected': ctrl.isSelected(day),
                                'today': ctrl.isToday(day),
                                'other-month': day.otherMonth,
                                'has-event': day.message
                            }" class="other-month">
                            <div class="span-wrap">
                                <span ng-style="day.fontColor &amp;&amp; {'color': day.fontColor }">
                                    30
                                </span>
                                <!---->
                            </div>
                        </td><!----><td ng-repeat="day in week.days" ng-click="ctrl.openDay(day, $event)" title="" ng-class="{
                                'closed': day.status === 1,
                                'past': day.status === 2,
                                'booked' : day.status === 3 || day.status === 5,
                                'waiting-list': day.status === 6 &amp;&amp; !day.otherMonth,
                                'selected': ctrl.isSelected(day),
                                'today': ctrl.isToday(day),
                                'other-month': day.otherMonth,
                                'has-event': day.message
                            }">
                            <div class="span-wrap">
                                <span ng-style="day.fontColor &amp;&amp; {'color': day.fontColor }">
                                    1
                                </span>
                                <!---->
                            </div>
                        </td><!---->
                    </tr><!---->
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <!---->
        </div>

and the XPATH: //*[@id="2029"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/div/span
for april the id is 2028, may 2029, june 2030 etc.
This is the result of the first month and the error message i'm getting in the second month:
//div[@id='2028']//tr[1]/td[contains(., '29')]
//div[@id='2028']//tr[2]/td[contains(., '29')]
//div[@id='2028']//tr[3]/td[contains(., '29')]
//div[@id='2028']//tr[4]/td[contains(., '29')]
//div[@id='2028']//tr[5]/td[contains(., '29')]
29 - 18:30 - Wachtlijst
29 - 18:45 - Wachtlijst
//div[@id='2028']//tr[1]/td[contains(., '30')]
//div[@id='2028']//tr[2]/td[contains(., '30')]
//div[@id='2028']//tr[3]/td[contains(., '30')]
//div[@id='2028']//tr[4]/td[contains(., '30')]
//div[@id='2028']//tr[5]/td[contains(., '30')]
30 - 18:30 - Wachtlijst
30 - 18:45 - Wachtlijst
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]
//div[@id='2029']//tr[1]/td[contains(., '1')]
1 - 18:30 - Wachtlijst
1 - 18:45 - Wachtlijst
//div[@id='2029']//tr[1]/td[contains(., '2')]
done
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ....
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: stale element not found


Would appreciate any suggestion, also improvements on the code that is not directly related to this problem.
I already tried to increase time.sleep, webdriver wait periods and a couple of other xpath combinations.

Does this answer your question? StaleElementReferenceException on Python Selenium

I've tried to implement this suggestion but unfortunately it didn't solve my problem. It still loops perfect over the current month but when moving to the next month it only gets the values for the first of the month..

The problem seems to be in the single day numbers: 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. These numbers give errors, could it be that the td[contains(., '{day}')] part doesnt know what number it needs to select in case of 2, it could also be 20,21,22 etc. ? I have tried some other options with td[text(), '{day}'] but this also doesnt work. Any other suggestion would be helpful
